# Reading utf-8 files to std::string in C++

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8, c++14

Finally! We're starting to require that all our input files are encoded in utf-8! This is something we've been wanting to do for *years*. Unfortunately, we suck at it since none of us have ever tried it and most of us are Windows programmers or are used to operating systems where utf-8 is the only real option anyway; neither group knows anything about reading utf-8 strings in a platform agnostic way.

So we started to look at how to deal with utf-8 in a platform agnostic way and found that its pretty confusing (because Windows) and the other questions I've found here on stackoverflow don't really seem to cover our scenario *or* they are confusing. I found a reference to https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-with-C-streams which, I find, is a bit confusing and contains a great deal of fluff.

So a few assumptions (that must be true or we're in a state of GIGO)

- All files are in utf-8 (yay!)
- The `std::string`s must contain utf-8; no conversion allowed.
- The solution must be locale agnostic and work on both macOS (10.13+), Windows (10+), Android and iOS 10+.
- Stream support is not required; we're dealing with local files only (for now), but support for streams is appreciated.

We're trying to avoid using `std::wstring` if we can and I see no reason to use it anyway. We're also trying to avoid using any third party libraries which do not use utf-8 encoded `std::string`; using a custom string with functions that overloads and converts all `std::string` arguments to the a custom string is acceptable.

Is there any way to do this using just the standard C++ library? Preferably just by imbuing the global locale with a facet that tells the stream library to just dump content of files in strings (using custom delimiters as usual); no conversion allowed.

This question is *only* about reading utf-8 files into `std::string`s and storing the content as utf-8 encoded strings. Dealing with Windows APIs and such is a separate concern.

C++17 is available.

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable-length *8-bit byte* encoding. On most systems today `char` (as used by `std::string`) is an *8-bit byte*. As long as you don't expect the `length` to be able to return the number of code points it should work as-is.

Comment: Those are not part of the confusion -- Windows locales is, pretty much, the only confusion.

Comment: Then I don't really understand this question. You say that "This question is *only* about reading utf-8 files into `std::string`s and storing the content as utf-8 encoded strings." Well that's pretty much answered by my comment. So if that's "not part of the confusion" then what is the reason for this question? What problems do you have with reading inot a `std::string`? Why did you post this question?

Comment: I assume you are already familiar with http://utf8everywhere.com ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 is just a sequence of bytes that follow a specific encoding. If you read a sequence of bytes that is legitimate UTF-8 data into a `std::string`, then the string contains UTF-8 data.

There's nothing special you have to actually do to make this happen. This works like any other C or C++ file loading. Just don't mess around with iostream locales and you'll be fine.